# Logging into multiple gmail accounts to read messages in inbox in java using imaps

Tags: java, gmail-imap, jakarta-mail

I'm beginner,
I'm writing a program which logins into my g-mail accounts and checks the messages in the Inbox.
To do this I'm using `imaps ("imaps.gmail.com")`.
But what my problem is while logging into all the accounts, checking the messages in it one by one.

> Program Reporting an error/kind of: 
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in via
>   your web browser: some url (Failure) imaps:   xxxx@gmail.com for the
>   second and other accounts...

From this What I understand is I'm not closing sessions, store properly. So,Program is unable to check in the respective second and rest mail accounts..
Someone Help (With clarification)..

And the architecture of my code:

```
public class InboxRead {

public static boolean release = false;
private Session session = null;

public void checkInbox(String username, String password) {
    // logging into account using imaps..

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, password);
        System.out.println(store);

        // reading inbox... closing all folders here

        store.close();
        session = null;
        release = true;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

for(;;) { // gives no of accounts with credentials..
    do {
        String username = "xxx@gmail.com";
        String password = "xxxx";

        InboxRead.checkInbox(username, password);
    } while(release);

}
}

}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Its a Google gateway thrown error. Google maintain high security in the aspect of profile access or even mail access but even that can be controlled by the user using below link [Google secure control](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

go to that link with your google account and select "turn on" and then try to execute your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any solution other than that ? Because I've multiple accounts which I've to open and read messages. So I can't open account and do  Secure Control to each one..